# How to increase header size limit in Java HttpsURLConnection?

Tags: java, header, request, size, limit

Trying to connect to web-service via url post request.

```
String SIGNATURE = "signature"; //(This data is huge)

String url = "someUrl";
URL obj = new URL(url);
HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

//add reuqest header
con.setRequestMethod("POST");
con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
con.setRequestProperty("PS-Sign",SIGNATURE);


// Send post request
con.setDoOutput(true);
DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
wr.flush();
wr.close();

int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();

    //print result
    System.out.println(response.toString());
```

`getInputStream()` throws exception: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: ...

I know that 400 may be returned for multiple reasons, but in this case I know 100% that this is caused by 'SIGNATURE' header. Characters are OK, its the size that causes bad request.

How do I increase the size limit?

Comment: What makes you think `HttpURLConnection` even has a header size limit? How do you know that it was a size error? What makes you think the limit is in the client side when the error came from the server? Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: 1.Initially I wrote the code on PHP, it returned 400 with description which said header was too big.
2.I think so because the web service works for long time and they would fix this error long time ago the problem if was on their side.

Comment: So if it doesn't work in PHP either why are you blaming `HttpURLConnection`? It doesn't begin to make sense.